# Which type of encrytion is this or how this string is encrypted?

Tags: string, encryption

I have an 10 digit number and its encrypted output. The only thing  I want to know that how this string is encrypted. Following are two given examples of it:

(a) original number: 1109010010

```
encrypted:  18E10B82029A046BEE09D86E31951E7BD67BD3619281BAF2C2661C183C7FC960EE52FAE640DA86BEA497364289E2156A543B7F18C333A025B2109AF6815151D65AEE68943A1D51DD42F425CFF752AA7FE60248F2D7680A939C592DEDF65D4053
```

(b) original number: 1009010096

```
encrypted: 19E2003A6B3DFB35CE3E9A51A70F16DBD491C749F0C75634D03F077F68726E5995B1216AC6776172E1B610D75211F0AC788575154B8C25DB460F6A13785B392164DDEF151971D31C5A5B3C0F07995B78410FC33CB94DADF339D4BD9F9E11E7F0
```

Please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a property of (decent) encryption algorithms that their output is indistinguishable from random, so **there's no way to tell for sure**.

For all you know, the number could have have been padded with a few zeros, and then encrypted using AES. Or that could be RSA. Or some dude's homegrown algorithm.

Why do you need to know this? Maybe there's another way we could help.

Comment: I want to develop a web application which takes input as the original 10 digit number and then encrypt it in above mentioned form. But I have only basic idea of md5 encryption. Please..